# React/Redux: GET axios call causing infinite loop, onSubmit method is not causing visual output to the user

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

After clicking on submit button in form with addBook action nested inside, data is passed into DB, but not outputting imidiately to the screen (i have to refresh page each time to output newly added data from DB).

I tried to put my getBooks function into `componentDidUpdate()` lifecycle hook, but it causes infinite loop.

**getBooks action**

```
export const getBooks = () => dispatch => {
 axios.get('https://damianlibrary.herokuapp.com/library')
  .then(res => dispatch({
    type: GET_BOOKS,
    payload: res.data
  }))
};
```

**addBook action**

```
export const addBook = book => dispatch => {
 axios.post('https://damianlibrary.herokuapp.com/library', book)
  .then(res => dispatch({
   type: ADD_BOOK,
   payload: res.data
  }))
};
```

**bookReducer**

```
const initialState = {
 books: []
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
 switch(action.type) {
  case GET_BOOKS:
   return {
    ...state,
    books: action.payload
   };
  case DELETE_BOOK:
   return {
    ...state,
    books: state.books.filter(book => book.book_id !== action.payload)
   };
  case ADD_BOOK:
   return {
    ...state,
    eventDetails: [action.payload, ...state.books]
   };
  default:
   return state;
 }
}
```

**Form.js component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addBook, getBooks } from '../../actions/bookActions';

import './Form.css';

class Form extends Component {

state = {
 name: '',
 author: '',
 isbn: ''
}

componentDidMount () {
 this.props.getBooks();
}

onChangeHandler = (e) => {
 this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
};

onSubmitHandler = (e) => {

 const {name, author, isbn} = this.state

      const newBook = {
      name: name,
      author: author,
      isbn: isbn
    }
    this.props.addBook(newBook);

    this.setState({
      name: '',
      author: '',
      isbn: ''
    })
  e.preventDefault();
}

render() {
 const { name, author, isbn } = this.state;

 return (
  <div className='formContainer'>
    <div className='form'>
      <form className='bookForm' onSubmit={this.onSubmitHandler.bind(this)}>
        <div className='inputs'>
          <input 
          type='text' 
          name='name'  
          placeholder='Book name'
          onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
          value={name}/>
          <input 
          type='text' 
          name='author'  
          placeholder='Book author'
          onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
          value={author}/>
          <input 
          type='text' 
          name='isbn'  
          placeholder='ISBN'
          onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
          value={isbn}/>
        </div>
        <div className='buttonSpace'>
          <button>Add book</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  )
 }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
 book: state.book
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addBook, getBooks })(Form);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the reducer you should return an updated reducer object. In the ADD_BOOK you add new property eventDetails. Do you use it somewhere?
Your new reducer look that: { books: [ initial book list ], eventDetails: [initial book list and new book]}. When you change eventDetails to books in ADD_BOOK, your book list will update without additional requests.

Comment: Wow, thanks. When i was writing my app i was thinking about previous one where i was using eventDetails. Thanks for pointing out that mistake ;)